# Carbon-cache fails to start with no error

Tags: centos, rhel, graphite

Trying to install Graphite on CentOS 7, I'm met with this curious situation.

When trying to start carbon-cache via service, it will report OK

```
Starting carbon-cache (via systemctl):                     [  OK  ]
```

When checking its status, however I get FAILED:

```
Usage: bin/carbon-cache.py {start|stop|restart|status}
                                                           [FAILED]
```

(Yes, failed is on another line).

Carbon-cache log doesn't show anything - it doesn't even write to it. Any ideas of what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Does it happen to the process executed without service/systemctl? Does it crash immediately? dmesg? /var/log/graphite/carbon-cache/console.log? strace?

Comment: what is the output of `journalctl -xe`?